# Expectation of an random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables. 
So i can write $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ but can i write $E[X^2]=E^2[X]$ ? I'm a little confused if X and Y are independent then would X be independent of itself?

Comment: If $X$ is independent of itself, then $P(X\in A)=P(X\in A,X\in A)=P(X\in A)^2$ hence $P(X\in A)=0$ or $1$, for every $A$. From there, it is not difficult to see that there must exist some $x$ such that $P(X=x)=1$. IOW, a nondegenerate random variable is never independent of itself (as common sense would also suggest...).

Answer (score 1):

No, $X$ is not independent from itself, so you can't write $E[X^2]\color{red}{=E^2[X]}$.

However, if you happen to have **two** independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, then you can write $E[X_1X_2]=E[X_1]E[X_2]$.

Picture it like this: throwing a dice two times to get two numbers is not the same as throwing just one dice and use that number twice.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the random variable X with the variance $\sigma^2$. Then

$Var(2\cdot X)=Var(x)+Var(X)+2Cov(X,X)=2\cdot Var(X)+2\cdot Cov(X,X)$$ $

$=2\cdot Var(X)+2\cdot Var(X)=4\cdot Var(X)$

The result correspond with the well known equation $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$. We can see that $Var(X)=Cov(X,X)$. $X$ is not independent from $X$.

And $Cov(X,X)=E(X\cdot X)-E(X)\cdot E(X)$. In your case $Cov(X,X)=0$. This is not true.